# Natbib-Multibib problem with prefix labels

Tags: bibtex, natbib, subdividing, multibib

I am facing a problem when using `natbib` together with `multibib` and label prefixes. I want to define two bibliographies: One for literature of other people, with numbered references, and one for my own literature, also with numbered references, but with a prefix "O" before each reference (the `multibib` `labeled` option). Without `natbib` (only using `multibib`), it works fine. But together with `natbib`, the "O" prefix vanishes in the text. In the bibliography, it is still there. I need to use `natbib` because the `sort&compress` feature.

Working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@ARTICLE{travis,
  author = {Brehm, M. and Kirchner, B.},
  title = {TRAVIS - A free Analyzer and Visualizer for Monte Carlo and Molecular
    Dynamics Trajectories},
  journal = {J. Chem. Inf. Model.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {51 (8)},
  pages = {2007-2023},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.11.27}
},
@ARTICLE{welton2001,
  author = {L. Cammarata and S. G. Kazarian and P. A. Salter and T. Welton},
  title = {Molecular states of water in room temperature ionic liquids},
  journal = {Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {5192-5200},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.12.11}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square, sort&compress, super, comma]{natbib} 
\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}

\newcites{O}{Own Publications}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

Citing my own literature\citeO{travis}.
Citing other people's literature\cite{welton2001}.

\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyleO{plain}
\bibliography{main}
\bibliographyO{main}

\end{document}
```

To compile this, you need to run bibtex separately on "main" and on "O".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve your result. (I had duplicated your references to check whether the sorting and compression works.)

You have to keep in mind that **the `natbib` package should be commented till you generate `O.bbl` and `<filename>.bbl`.** That is to load the `natbib` package once you generate the `bbl` files using `bibtex`. Otherwise, the `\citation` entries will only write to `<filename>.aux` and the `O.bbl` will generate with no `\bibitem{...}`. This will be kept in your mind in later stage when you edit your `main.bib` file.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@ARTICLE{travis,
  author = {Brehm, M. and Kirchner, B.},
  title = {TRAVIS - A free Analyzer and Visualizer for Monte Carlo and Molecular
    Dynamics Trajectories},
  journal = {J. Chem. Inf. Model.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {51 (8)},
  pages = {2007-2023},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.11.27}
},
@ARTICLE{travis1,
  author = {Brehm, M. and Kirchner, B.},
  title = {TRAVIS - A free Analyzer and Visualizer for Monte Carlo and Molecular
    Dynamics Trajectories},
  journal = {J. Chem. Inf. Model.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {51 (8)},
  pages = {2007-2023},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.11.27}
},
@ARTICLE{travis2,
  author = {Brehm, M. and Kirchner, B.},
  title = {TRAVIS - A free Analyzer and Visualizer for Monte Carlo and Molecular
    Dynamics Trajectories},
  journal = {J. Chem. Inf. Model.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {51 (8)},
  pages = {2007-2023},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.11.27}
},
@ARTICLE{travis3,
  author = {Brehm, M. and Kirchner, B.},
  title = {TRAVIS - A free Analyzer and Visualizer for Monte Carlo and Molecular
    Dynamics Trajectories},
  journal = {J. Chem. Inf. Model.},
  year = {2011},
  volume = {51 (8)},
  pages = {2007-2023},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.11.27}
},
@ARTICLE{welton2001,
  author = {L. Cammarata and S. G. Kazarian and P. A. Salter and T. Welton},
  title = {Molecular states of water in room temperature ionic liquids},
  journal = {Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {5192-5200},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.12.11}
}
@ARTICLE{welton20011,
  author = {L. Cammarata and S. G. Kazarian and P. A. Salter and T. Welton},
  title = {Molecular states of water in room temperature ionic liquids},
  journal = {Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {5192-5200},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.12.11}
}
@ARTICLE{welton20012,
  author = {L. Cammarata and S. G. Kazarian and P. A. Salter and T. Welton},
  title = {Molecular states of water in room temperature ionic liquids},
  journal = {Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {5192-5200},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.12.11}
}
@ARTICLE{welton20013,
  author = {L. Cammarata and S. G. Kazarian and P. A. Salter and T. Welton},
  title = {Molecular states of water in room temperature ionic liquids},
  journal = {Phys. Chem. Chem. Phys.},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {5192-5200},
  owner = {Brehministrator},
  timestamp = {2011.12.11}
}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,sort&compress,super,comma]{natbib} %%Comment on first run

\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}

\newcites{O}{Own Publications}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{natbib}{%
\expandafter\DeclareRobustCommand\csname cite\@suffix\endcsname
    {\begingroup\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue\NAT@swatrue
      \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@cites}{\NAT@fullfalse\csname NAT@cites\@suffix\endcsname}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname NAT@cites\@suffix\endcsname{\@ifnextchar [{\csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname}{%
     \ifNAT@numbers\else
     \NAT@swafalse
     \fi
    \csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname[]}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname NAT@citetp\@suffix\endcsname{\@ifnextchar[{\csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname}{\csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname[]}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname{}
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@@citetp\@suffix\endcsname[#1]{\@ifnextchar[{\csname @citex\@suffix\endcsname[#1]}{\csname @citex\@suffix\endcsname[][#1]}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname NAT@set@cites\@suffix\endcsname{%
  \ifNAT@numbers
    \ifNAT@super \let\@cite\NAT@citesuper
       \def\NAT@mbox##1{\unskip\nobreak\textsuperscript{##1}}%
       \let\citeyearpar=\citeyear
       \let\NAT@space\relax
       \def\NAT@super@kern{\kern\p@}%
    \else
       \let\NAT@mbox=\mbox
       \let\@cite\NAT@citenum
       \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
       \let\NAT@super@kern\relax
    \fi
    \expandafter\let\csname @citex\@suffix\expandafter\endcsname\csname NAT@citexnum\@suffix\endcsname
    \let\@biblabel\NAT@biblabelnum
    \let\@bibsetup\NAT@bibsetnum
    \renewcommand\NAT@idxtxt{\NAT@name\NAT@spacechar\NAT@open\NAT@num\NAT@close}%
    \def\natexlab##1{}%
    \def\NAT@penalty{\penalty\@m}%
  \else
    \let\@cite\NAT@cite
    \let\@citex\NAT@citex
    \let\@biblabel\NAT@biblabel
    \let\@bibsetup\NAT@bibsetup
    \let\NAT@space\NAT@spacechar
    \let\NAT@penalty\@empty
    \renewcommand\NAT@idxtxt{\NAT@name\NAT@spacechar\NAT@open\NAT@date\NAT@close}%
    \def\natexlab##1{##1}%
  \fi}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname NAT@sep\@suffix\endcsname{,\@suffix}
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@separator\@suffix\endcsname{\csname NAT@sep\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@penalty}%
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@def@citea\@suffix\endcsname{\def\@citea{\csname NAT@separator\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@space}}%
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@def@citea@space\@suffix\endcsname{\def\@citea{\csname NAT@separator\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@spacechar}}%
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@def@citea@close\@suffix\endcsname{\def\@citea{\NAT@@close\csname NAT@separator\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@space}}%
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@def@citea@box\@suffix\endcsname{\def\@citea{\NAT@mbox{\NAT@@close}\csname NAT@separator\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@spacechar}}%
\expandafter\def\csname NAT@citexnum\@suffix\endcsname[#1][#2]#3{%
  \NAT@reset@parser
  \NAT@sort@cites{#3}%
  \NAT@reset@citea
  \@cite{\def\NAT@num{-1}\let\NAT@last@yr\relax\let\NAT@nm\@empty
    \@for\@citeb:=\NAT@cite@list\do
    {\@safe@activestrue
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \@safe@activesfalse
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
       {\reset@font\bfseries?}
        \NAT@citeundefined\PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
     {\let\NAT@last@num\NAT@num\let\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm
      \NAT@parse{\@citeb}%
      \ifNAT@longnames\@ifundefined{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
        \let\NAT@name=\NAT@all@names
        \global\@namedef{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{}}{}%
      \fi
      \ifNAT@full\let\NAT@nm\NAT@all@names\else
        \let\NAT@nm\NAT@name\fi
      \ifNAT@swa
       \@ifnum{\NAT@ctype>\@ne}{%
        \@citea
        \NAT@hyper@{\@ifnum{\NAT@ctype=\tw@}{\NAT@test{\NAT@ctype}}{\NAT@alias}}%
       }{%
        \@ifnum{\NAT@cmprs>\z@}{%
         \NAT@ifcat@num\NAT@num
          {\let\NAT@nm=\NAT@num}%
          {\def\NAT@nm{-2}}%
         \NAT@ifcat@num\NAT@last@num
          {\@tempcnta=\NAT@last@num\relax}%
          {\@suffix\@tempcnta\m@ne}%
         \@ifnum{\NAT@nm=\@tempcnta}{%
          \@ifnum{\NAT@merge>\@ne}{}{\NAT@last@yr@mbox}%
         }{%
           \advance\@tempcnta by\@ne
           \@ifnum{\NAT@nm=\@tempcnta}{%
             \ifx\NAT@last@yr\relax
               \def@NAT@last@yr{\@citea}%
             \else
               \def@NAT@last@yr{--\NAT@penalty\@suffix}%
             \fi
           }{%
             \NAT@last@yr@mbox
           }%
         }%
        }{%
         \@tempswatrue
         \@ifnum{\NAT@merge>\@ne}{\@ifnum{\NAT@last@num=\NAT@num\relax}{\@tempswafalse}{}}{}%
         \if@tempswa\NAT@citea@mbox\fi
        }%
       }%
       \csname NAT@def@citea\@suffix\endcsname
      \else
        \ifcase\NAT@ctype
          \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm \NAT@yrsep\NAT@penalty\NAT@space\else
            \@citea \NAT@test{\@ne}\NAT@spacechar\NAT@mbox{\NAT@super@kern\NAT@@open}%
          \fi
          \if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi
          \NAT@mbox{\NAT@hyper@{{\citenumfont{\NAT@num}}}}%
          \csname NAT@def@citea@box\@suffix\endcsname
        \or
          \csname NAT@hyper@citea@space\@suffix\endcsname{\NAT@test{\NAT@ctype}}%
        \or
          \csname NAT@hyper@citea@space\@suffix\endcsname{\NAT@test{\NAT@ctype}}%
        \or
          \csname NAT@hyper@citea@space\@suffix\endcsname\NAT@alias
        \fi
      \fi
     }%
    }%
      \@ifnum{\NAT@cmprs>\z@}{\NAT@last@yr}{}%
      \ifNAT@swa\else
        \@ifnum{\NAT@ctype=\z@}{%
          \if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi
        }{}%
        \NAT@mbox{\NAT@@close}%
      \fi
  }{#1}{#2}%
}%
\csname NAT@set@cites\@suffix\endcsname
}{}
\def\mycite{\csname cite\@suffix\endcsname}
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

Citing my own literature\mycite{travis} and\mycite{travis,travis3} and\mycite[p.~1]{travis,travis3,travis2,travis1} and\mycite{travis,travis3,travis1}
Citing other people's literature\cite{welton2001} and\cite{welton2001,welton20013} and\cite[p.~1]{welton2001,welton20013,welton20012,welton20011} and\cite{welton2001,welton20013,welton20011}.

\appendix
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyleO{plain}
\bibliography{main}
\bibliographyO{main}

\end{document}
```

The macros which are defined between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are taken from `natbib` package.

The output will look like:
[image: Text citation]
[image: Other people's literature]
[image: Own literature]

Comment: Thank you, this works also for me.However, to insert a bunch of TeX macros into my document seems more like a hack. Natbib and Multibib both officially state that they are compatible to each other... I suppose this should be patched in either of the two packages.

Comment: are there any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick hack using `natbib`'s `\citenumfont`, though it means each `\newcite` will need their own patch lines.

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oriCiteO\citeO

%% The O{} in this re-definition means "an optional argument
%% with an empty default value". It is not related to the
%% "O" prefix in the OP's example. 
\RenewDocumentCommand{\citeO}{O{} O{} m}{%
  %% The "O" here *is* the prefix as required by the OP's example
  \renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{O##1}%  
  \oriCiteO[#1][#2]{#3}%
  \renewcommand{\citenumfont}[1]{##1}%
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this breaks any other `natbib` behavior, so try with care!

Comment: I know it is a hack, but it saved two days of searching

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this

Comment: Yes, thank you!