# multibib: wrong label?

Tags: bibtex, subdividing, multibib

I would like to produce a document with two lists of references. One should have numbered items, another should have "E" prepended to the number. Here is my solution that does not work

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\usepackage[]{times}
\usepackage[varg]{txfonts}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{E}{Other references}

\begin{document}
\section{Example}
This is one paper~\cite{hedin_new_1965}
\section{Another example}
This is another paper~\citeE{kohn_self-consistent_1965}.
\bibliography{MyLibrary}
\bibliographystyleE{apsrev4-1}
\bibliographyE{MyLibrary}
\end{document}
```

My bibliography is as follows:

```
@article{hedin_new_1965,
 title =     {New Method for Calculating the One-Particle Green's Function with
              Application to the Electron-Gas Problem},
 volume =    139,
 number =    {{3A}},
 journal =   {Phys. Rev.},
 author =    {Hedin, Lars},
 year =  1965,
 pages =     {A796--A823},
 }

@article{kohn_self-consistent_1965,
 title =     {Self-Consistent Equations Including Exchange and Correlation Effects},
 volume =    140,
 number =    {4A},
 journal =   {Phys. Rev.},
 author =    {Kohn, W. and Sham, L. J.},
 year =  1965,
 pages =     {A1133--A1138},
 }
```

After running *pdflatex example.tex + bibtex example + bibtex E + (x2) pdflatex example.tex* I've obtained:

[image: screen-shot]
As you see, the "E" is missing. Am I doing something wrong?

**Bonus question**

Is it possible to make labels of the second list of references to be numerals in boldface?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug caused by the combination natbib and multibib.  Cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124805/15925

Comment: @ Andrew Swann Indeed this seems to be relevant. Even though I am using tex for while the solution looks to me horrendously difficult. Hope, someone will suggest a simpler approach or the bug will be fixed...